# how to fade in div on after check confirm ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS

```
    function CheckFedderalTimeStatus(){
    var answer = confirm('Federal law restricts sending of mobile text messages between 9PM and 8AM of recipient`s local time. If you believe that the nature of your message does not fall under this restriction (e.g. emergency alert), please click OK to apply for an exception.');

    if(answer){
        $("#inline2").fadeIn(300);
        $(".overlay-fixed").fadeIn(300);
        $(".fancybox-opened").fadeIn(300);
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location = "sendmsg.php";
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="CheckFedderalTimeStatus()">fade In </a>
<div id="inline2" style="width:650px;display: none; font-size:14px; overflow:scroll"> hello </div>
```

i just want to open this box in pop up box on click ok on confirm box and page refresh on cancel button

Comment: Please clarify your needs and what do you mean by want to open this box in pop up box?

Comment: @VaibhavKatole i want to open this box in popup box

Comment: do you want to reload your current page when cancel button is clicked?

Comment: Is the apparent typo in your function name ('Fedderal' instead of the, correct, 'Federal') deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

The function, `CheckFedderalTimeStatus()`, is not available globally.

Here is the modified code:

JS

```
<script>
 window.CheckFedderalTimeStatus = function(){
      var answer = confirm('Federal law restricts sending of mobile text messages between 9PM
and 8AM of recipient`s local time. If you believe that the nature of your message does
not fall under this restriction (e.g. emergency alert), please click OK to apply for an
exception.');

if(answer){
   $("#inline2").fadeIn(300);
   $(".overlay-fixed").fadeIn(300);
   $(".fancybox-opened").fadeIn(300);
   return false;
}
else {
  location.reload(); // reload the page
  //window.location = "sendmsg.php";
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

Here is the demo : [http://jsfiddle.net/z9cry2tp/](http://jsfiddle.net/z9cry2tp/3/)

Comment: Your fiddle shows console error. 'Uncaught ReferenceError: CheckFedderalTimeStatus is not defined ' Please check.

Comment: @VaibhavKatole : Oh, I didn't see that error checked from multiple browsers. Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/z9cry2tp/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to stay you current page as it is, then you can simply `return false` from your `else` part,

```
else {
    location.reload(); // use this if you want to reload page anyway.
    return false;
}
```

For the `if` part, what I could figure out is that you want to show the '#inline2' element in pop up box. [PLEASE SEE THE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/52/). I guess this is what you want?